# I'm looking for a terminal editor with Ctrl-Backspace/C functionality

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, text-editor, editor

I need a terminal based text editor where I can delete a word before the cursor with Ctrl-Backspace and a word after the cursor with Ctrl-Delete. Other editor functionality is welcomed as well ;)

Comment: Well, do you mind slightly steep learning curve ? Do you want to have exactly those shortcuts or is functionality of deleting words is more important ?

Comment: Of course, my minimum expectation is to have a solution to delete whole words but I in case of another shortcut the editor probably have different shortcuts for other actions as well. This is an unnecessary burden.

Answer (score 0):

**Vi/Vim** has somehow a hard learning curve, but it does what you ask for and pretty much more by default, also its present on near any **nix* system.

It as different modes, mainly *Normal* and *Insert*. While in *Normal mode* you can issue `cw` to change from cursor to the end of the word or `cb` to make the same from cursor to *beginning* of the current word.

If you dislike usual vim commands, you can bind your own key combos, check [this link](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-map-ctrl-del-to-delete-word-td1168842.html) for something similar to your requirements.

Hope it helps.